# Display calendar on top of the keyboard

Tags: android, iphone, asp.net-mvc, mobile

I have site with couple kendo ui date pickers. 
When I view it on android/iphone phone I press the date field first.
Keyboard is displayed, then I click on he calendar icon and the date look-up is displayed behind the keyboard.
Is there a away to display the calendar look-up on top of keyboard?

Comment: Did you try to do it with z-index in your css?

Comment: Yes I have tried and it doesn't really work.